# Logout Timer in Marketing Cloud/Exact Target

Tags: marketing-cloud, logout

Can I change the timer that SFMC has for logging out?  It seems to be too frequent.

Very basic question, but also a very basic annoyance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change this setting like this:

1. Hover over your name (top right corner)
2. Click on Administration
3. Navigate to *Security -> Security Settings*
4. Click Edit
5. Select the desired timeout
6. Click Save

[image: Session Settings]

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: FYI - This is a global setting if you have god-like access.  
Happen to know if there's a way to personalize this for my username and not for my users?

Comment: I'm afraid there is no such setting that can be configured per user, at least as far as I know.